# Can not deploy to IPhone from Xamarin Forms

Tags: ios, xcode, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I’ve recently started making an app on Xamarin Forms and went to test it using Free Provisioning following the Documentation Guide here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/device-provisioning/free-provisioning?tabs=vsmac

However whenever I go to test my app I can only build it but not install it on my IPhone. Every time I got deploy it, it only comes up with the hammer. I’m currently working on Visual Studio for Mac and am really confused.

Is the link I have provided outdated or am I missing something?

Thanks, Ryan

Comment: Were you able to get a blank app to deploy to your phone directly from Xcode as described in the link you posted?  If that works, then deployment from Xamarin will likely work as well.

Comment: @DavidS. I was able to deploy the blank app which really confuses me, just can't deploy from xamarin

Comment: Did you select your Provisioning Profile?

Comment: @SümeyyaTuğçeArar yeah i've selected it from both xcode and visual studio

Comment: @trafficjam Did you see the error on the Application Output? If so, what error does it show?